# Best way to merge two contacts in crm project?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-3

i have a question about merging contacts.
I have a visual studio 2010 (MVC3 and Razor) project that manages contacts.
Every logged user can add, edit and remove contacts and even share his contacts with other users. The thing is that if the user is about to create a contact and this contact already exists, i need a way to merge this two or even more "equal" contacts into one (checking some things before this like the name of both, etc).
What is the best practice to do this?
In my mysql database, i have a contacts table that stores the idcontact and the data.
I dont know where to store this new "merged contact"... is in another table that contains the id's of the merged contacts?

How can i do this?
I hope you can help me, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After this question, now in my logic its more complicated to doit, so i will think again how to do my merge.
Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

When a user is creating a new contact, search the existing list of contacts  (based on the name the user entered) and return a list of matching contacts.  (This is like the way stack overflow tries to eliminate people asking duplicate questions.)

Comment: Yes, that part i can doit, but, with that list... i should let the user, chose the correct contact and edit the data of that contact avoiding creating the new contact? but what if the user creates the contact anyway? What i need is not a match contact with the one that i am creating.. what i need is a way to merge two or more contacts that i have already created.